# Fetching last rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to retrieve the last ocurrence of each user from the table below.

```
| ID | NAME | FLAG |                     CREATED_AT |
|----|------|------|--------------------------------|
|  1 | John |    1 | January, 15 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  2 | Mary |    1 | January, 16 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  3 | John |    0 | January, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  4 | John |    1 | January, 18 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  5 | John |    0 | January, 19 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  6 | Mary |    0 | January, 20 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  7 | John |    1 | January, 21 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

The correct result should be (order doesn't matter):

```
| NAME | FLAG |                MAX(CREATED_AT) |
|------|------|--------------------------------|
| John |    1 | January, 21 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
| Mary |    0 | January, 20 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

But my result is (flag is incorrect for Mary):

```
| NAME | FLAG |                MAX(CREATED_AT) |
|------|------|--------------------------------|
| John |    1 | January, 21 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
| Mary |    1 | January, 20 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

The query I'm using is this:

```
SELECT name, flag, max(created_at)
FROM logs
GROUP BY name
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a MySQL extension to `group by` that the documentation explicitly warns against.  The extension is referring to a column in the `select` that is not in the `group by`.  The value is arbitrary.  See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Here is a way to rewrite the query:

```
SELECT name, substring_index(group_concat(flag order by created_at desc), ',', 1) as flag, max(created_at)
FROM logs
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: well, if we're going to stoop so low as to reference the manual... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Excellent reference.  Particularly notable is the lack of a subquery with an `order by` in it -- a mistake often seen here.